# axios post working fine and data being saved to backend URL but still getting CORS policy error on frontend app in vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

I know this question has been asked many times , I've tried most of the solutions and hence I'm able to post data from axios.post() in Vue JS.But the actual problem is even though data is being sent to Mongoose and is being saved successfully , I'm still getting CORS policy error on frontend app(Code and scenario are given below):

I'm creating simple User Sign Up page in which data is sent from "frontendURL" to "backendURL" using axios.post() and then this post is caught using app.post("/addUser",//save user in Mongoose DB) in backendURL.The code is always going inside of catch block in axios.The code in frontend App is

```
if (
        this.name &&
        this.number.length == 10 &&
        this.email &&
        this.pincode.length == 6 &&
        this.minimumAge
      ) {
        axios({
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
          url: 'backendURL/addUser',
          data:qs.stringify(
          {
            name: this.name,
            number: this.number,
            email: this.email,
            pincode: this.pincode,
            minimumAge: this.minimumAge,
          }) 
        }).then((dataFromAPI) => {
            this.userAddedSuccessfully = 200;
            console.log("User added to Database successfully" + dataFromAPI);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            this.userAddedSuccessfully=404
            console.log(err + "OP OP");
          });
      } else {
        this.userAddedSuccessfully = 201;
        console.log("Some entries in your form are missing");
      }
```

And the code which handles the post request in backend is

```
app.post("/addUser", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  let temporaryUser = new dataUsers({
    name: req.body.name,
    number: req.body.number,
    email: req.body.email,
    minimumAge: req.body.minimumAge,
    pincode: req.body.pincode,
    notificationsCount: 0,
  });
  temporaryUser.save(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error while adding user to Database");
      res.send("Error while adding user to Database ");
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log("User added to Database successfully");
      res.status(200).send("User added to Database successfully");
    }
  });
});
```

I'm able to save User in Database on backend URL but still getting CORS policy error on fronted app.
Already Thanks for the solution , if I'm not able to explain the scenario feel free to comment so that I can edit the question and will help others facing the same issue ;)

Comment: CORS errors means you can't access the response - the request can still happen - does the server send CORS headers?

Comment: There are several [CORS errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors). Which one?

Comment: Have you tried setting cors policy headers on the server?

Comment: When I set the cors allow headers it's working smoothly , The code which I added on server side was `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
`  .But I've seen in other answers that even though this will work and help me bypass cors policy, it isn't recommended on production . Can anyone explain why ?! and since this code helped me solve the issue should I post it as an answer to this question